# I want to simulate client/server scenario in omnet++?

Tags: c++, networking, simulation, omnet++

I want to simulate a network using OmNET++, in which a node (`client1`) sends a request for data to other node (`client2` / server). In response to this request, that node (`client2` / server) sends a reply by sending a UDP packet with data inside. How I can create a UDP request in OMNeT++ and then a UDP packet to fulfil this request?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have omnet++ installed.

1. Install [inet package](http://inet.omnetpp.org/index.php?n=Main.Download) for the omnet++ package.
2. Once you have inet package you will get examples folder. See some client-server examples (TCP) and get [udp burst example](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/master/examples/inet/udpburst) running and understand it. Finally tailor it to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please tell me where .cc and .h files are defined for node and server that are used in udpburst example.